# Rails action mailer - wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm working on building my mailer and am getting the Error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):
  
app/mailers/blog_mailer.rb:2:in `blog_created'
```

I have passed the blog object in my method in the controller:

`blogs_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)
  @blog.user = current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    if @blog.save
      BlogMailer.blog_created(@blog).deliver_later
      format.html { redirect_to @blog, notice: "Blog was successfully created." }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @blog }
    else
      format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

`blog_mailer.rb`

```
class BlogMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def blog_created(blog)
    @blog = blog
    mail(
      from: "info@testing.com",
      to: User.first.email,
      cc: User.all.pluck(:email),
      bcc: "info@testing.com",
      subject: @blog.title
    )
  end
end
```

can anyone help with what the issue is?

Comment: What is the line pointed to by the error message? aka What is line 8 in `blog_mailer.rb`? In the given example it's `bcc: "info@testing.com",` but I have the feeling it's not. Could you add a comment behind the related line?

Comment: Sorry, it's line 2. I cleaned the code up after I copied the error. I have edited it above

Comment: problem line is ` def blog_created(blog)`

Comment: Could you share more of the error stack? At least all lines referring to project related files. It all looks like it is supposed to work. However maybe the method is called in a different way than you expect.